# Is there a way to verify that value labels are defined consistently across a number of datasets?

Tags: stata

I have many datasets that have a panel identifier that is a labeled integer. The files were put together by several co-authors and RAs, so I am worried that value labels are not consistent and that a merge will be wrong. For example, if Firm ABC is 1 and 11. The data is `xtset`, so these cannot be stored as a string.

Is there a way to check that for a given a variable, the value labels are consistent across datasets? There's too many panels and datasets to check by hand.

Here's a toy example of what I am trying to avoid:

```
clear
tempfile f1
clear
input id
1 
2
end
label define idlab 1 "One" 2 "Two"
lab val id idlab
save `f1'

clear
input id
1 
2
end

label define idlab 1 "Three" 2 "Four"
lab val id idlab

merge 1:1 id using `f1', nogen

list, clean noobs
```

Comment: This is hard even assuming that all the variable names are the same (if not, an extra problem) and that all those variables have value labels attached (same comment). Evidently having the same value label name attached is neither necessary nor sufficient. I'd create `decode`d copies of the variables and then `encode` again once the `merge`s are done.

Comment: Sound advice. Thank you, @NickCox!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use `value label` and `label` [macro extended functions](https://www.stata.com/help.cgi?extended_fcn) to validate if value labels are consistent accross datasets. My strategy would be:

1. to load a dataset with the label values that I consider the more adequate.
2. loop through all datasets
3. get all the values of variable `id`
4. get the name of the label value with the `value label` macro function
5. get the label of every value of `id` with the `label` macro function
6. compare the "adequate" value label with the value label of this dataset

If you detect that the label is different for some value, you could do something to change it.

This would be the strategy to verify with your toy code:

```
clear
tempfile f1
clear
input id
1 
2
end
label define idlab 1 "One" 2 "Two"
lab val id idlab
levelsof id, local(values_id) 
global labelvname1 : value label id

foreach x of local values_id{
    global labelvname1_`x' : label ${labelvname1} `x'
}
save `f1'

clear
input id
1 
2
end

label define idlab 1 "Three" 2 "Four"
lab val id idlab

global labelvname2 : value label id
foreach x of local values_id{
    global labelvname2_`x' : label ${labelvname2} `x'
    if "${labelvname1_`x'}"!="${labelvname2_`x'}"{
        display "Label values are different for value `x'"
    }

}
```

I hope this help.